# Why does initialising a vector of vectors (Vec<Vec<T>>) expect a T instead of a Vec<T>?

Tags: rust

I missed something with the initialization of a vector of vectors.
In a first approach, I tried this code:

```
let mut landFirst: Vec<Vec<char>> = Vec::with_capacity(width);
for v in landFirst {
    v.push(Vec::with_capacity(height));
}
```

But it failed:

```
v.push(Vec::with_capacity(height));
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected char, found struct `std::vec::Vec`
```

Why? `v` is composed of `Vec<char>`, not of `char`.

It works with this code:

```
let mut landFirst: Vec<Vec<char>> = Vec::with_capacity(width);
for cpt in 0..width {
    landFirst.insert(cpt, Vec::with_capacity(height));
}
```

Can you enlighten me please?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `land_first` instead, please.

Comment: Note that a vec of vec is often not a "good" code.

Comment: @Stargateur I agree with you, I don't like this. But what is the good way to get a 2d array with Vec ?

Comment: @Edrae Take a look at https://github.com/bluss/ndarray

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why? `v` is composed of `Vec<char>`, not of `char`.

Let's check the type of `v`:

```
for v in land_first {
    let () = v;
}
```

This results in:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:13
  |
7 |         let () = v;
  |             ^^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<char>`
             found type `()`
```

So the `v` has the type `Vec<char>`. Why? Well with `for v in land_first` you iterate through all elements of `land_first`. What are the elements of `land_first`? Correct: `Vec<char>`.

Another thing you confused: `Vec::with_capacity()` only reserves memory, but doesn't actually insert elements. `Vec::with_capacity(10).len()` is 0! You need to use `push()` or `insert()` to actually insert elements.

This also hints at the core problem of your approach: **what do you think are the characters in your vectors?** You never specified which character to insert. There is no clear default that's always useful, right?

---

So how would you ideally initialize your vector of vectors? There is the useful `vec![]` macro:

```
const INIT_CHAR: char = '❤';
let land_first = vec![vec![INIT_CHAR; height]; width];
```

---

Also note:

- I changed `landFirst` to `land_first`. In Rust, variable names use `snake_case`.
- I removed the explicit type annotation: those are usually not necessary in Rust.

Comment: You points it : I'm confused ! I'm learning the language and mixed with those I know. I wanted to add elements without "nullpointerExcepetion". But as you said, I only reserved memory and I did not add any character. This make sense. Also, thanks for the note on snake_case. (Thank you for the whole answer actually.)

Comment: @Edrae What are you confused about? I didn't quite understand your comment :/

Comment: @Edrae No problem! I'm glad I could help. Remember that you can mark one answer as "accepted" to tell others that it helped you. You don't need to do that now, but here on SO it's expected that you do eventually if an answer helped you. Also: if you need more help with your first steps in Rust, you could [join the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) and maybe get some quick feedback to small questions.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your first code sample is not going to do what you expect, `landFirst` is still empty, even if you initialize it with a capacity, it has no items, so the for loop will never be entered.

As you are iterating over the elements of `landFirst`, `v` is a `Vec<char>`, so you can only push a `char` to it, your second code sample differs in that you are pushing to `landFirst`, not pushing to an element contained within `landFirst`.

Your second code sample will properly initialize `landFirst`, however it can be rewritten as the following:

```
let mut landFirst = vec![Vec::with_capacity(height); width];
```